# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'like_post' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P[0-9]+)/like/$']

Tags: python, django

> NoReverseMatch at /
>
> Reverse for 'like_post' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s)
>    tried: ['(?P[0-9]+)/like/$']

---

I suspect there is some issue with my form but I'm unable to point out exactly whats wrong

---

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Blog

class BlogsList(ListView):
    model=Blog
    template_name='blog/home.html'
    context_object_name='blogs'
    ordering=['-date_posted']



def like_post(request, blog_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Blog, id=blog_id)
    post.likes.add(request.user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(Blog.get_absolute_url())
```

---

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse 

class Blog(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content=models.TextField()
    date_posted=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='likes',blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

---

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views 

urlpatterns=[
path('',views.BlogsList.as_view(),name='blog-home'),
path('<int:blog_id>/like/', views.like_post, name='like_post')
]
```

---

html code

```
{{ user.username }}
{% block content %}
    {% for post in blogs %}
        <article class="media content-section">
          <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}">
          <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
              <h2>{{ post.author }}</h2>
              <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
            </div>
            <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
            <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <form action="{% url 'like_post' blog_id %}">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <button type='submit' name='blog_id' value="{{ blog_id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Like</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </article>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What do you think `blog_id` is in your template? (`{% url 'like_post' blog_id %}`) Where did you define that variable?

Answer (score 1):

In your template, `blog_id` is not define (no contexte provided?).

You should change `blog_id` to `post.id`:

```html
<form action="{% url 'like_post' post.id %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button type='submit' name='blog_id' value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Like</button>
</form>
```